# Unmarshalling of Composite Objects in REST API

Tags: json, rest, jersey, jackson, resteasy

I am having following data structure:

```
    class User {
      String name;
      ContactDetails contactDetails;
    }

    class ContactDetails {
      String street;
      String area;
    }

    class PersonalContactDetails extends ContactDetails {
      String mobileNumber;
    }

    class OfficeContactDetails extends ContactDetails {
      String officeNumber;
    }
```

In above data structure, the ContactDetails field in User Object can contain Objects of type 'PersonalContactDetails' or 'OfficeContactDetails'.

The request can contain following JSON string:

```
    {
      "name" : "John",
      "contactDetails" : {
                    "street" : "7",
                    "area" : "NY",
                    "mobileNumber" : "9898xxxxx"
                  }
    }
```

The unmarshalling of above JSON string gives Object of User with contactDetails field containing only two arguments i.e. street and area.

I want the output of unmarshall to have Object of PersonalContactDetails class set in ContactDetails field with valid mobileNumber.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request needs to show the type of the subclass:

```
 {
      "name" : "John",
      "contactDetails" : {
                    "@type" : "PersonalContactDetails",  
                    "street" : "7",
                    "area" : "NY",
                    "mobileNumber" : "9898xxxxx"
      }
 }
```

To show that extra **@type** property use the following annotations:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(PersonalContactDetails.class),

    @JsonSubTypes.Type(OfficeContactDetails.class) }
)
class ContactDetails {
      String street;
      String area;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is the solution which does not need to add **@type** annotation to input JSON:

```
     {
       "name" : "John",
       "contactDetails" : {
           "street" : "7",
           "area" : "NY",
           "mobileNumber" : "9898xxxxx"
       }
      }
```

Following are the annotations applied on Data classes:

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = “type”)
    @JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(PersonalContactDetails.class, name="PersonalContactDetails"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(OfficeContactDetails.class, name="OfficeContactDetails") }
    )
    class ContactDetails {
        String street;
        String area;
    }

    @JsonTypeName("PersonalContactDetails")
    class PersonalContactDetails extends ContactDetails {
        String mobileNumber;
    }

    @JsonTypeName("OfficeContactDetails")
    class OfficeContactDetails extends ContactDetails {
        String officeNumber;
    }
```